# Change username into new user name, Django

Tags: django-views

I want the user to be able to change his username
so i tried this code and its not working any one can help!

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        new_name = request.POST['new_name']
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            user = authenticate(username=new_name,password=password) 
            return redirect('userr')
    return render(request, 'index/edit.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

*You'll need to import the 'UserProfileForm' into your **views.py.***

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import User
from django import forms

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ''
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Username'
        self.fields[
            'username'].help_text = '<span class="mb-3">Choose a new username</span>'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .form import UserProfileForm

def edit(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        """
            First, you will need to figure out who the current user is.

            -- Notice that we're calling the user module.
        """
        current_user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

        """
        then you will have to pass the instance of this <current_user> into the UserProfileForm.

            -- Notice that I have used request.POST or None, since they will either be going to the page or posting the page.
               If they're going to the page we just want to show the page, if they're posting the page we want to do something else.
        """
        user_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=current_user)

        # test if the user_form is valid
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # save the form
            user_form.save()
            # You might want to be logged in after submitting the form.
            login(request, current_user)
            message = format_html('<span>Profile updated successfully — <a href="{}" style="color: #2f81f7 !important;">view your profile</a>.</span>', reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': current_user.id}))
            messages.info(request, message)
            return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
        # Lastly, you just need to pass the user_form to the page.
        return render(request, 'user/edit.html', {'user_form': user_form})
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'You must be logged in...')
        return redirect('home')
```

Note: Try code as per your variable names

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).